# How Formal is 为期 (wei2qi1)－ to last？

Tags: grammar

In a recent podcast I've been listening to - imandarinpod - the term 为期 was mentioned. It was loosely explained to mean "to last" as in for a period of time. 
I know that we can say something like "回忆为期三天“ - which makes sense. But, in all of the examples of 为期 I've seen it looks like it has been for "intentional periods of time". Could I say something in the past tense that wasn't expected like

"战争为期十年“?

Also, how formal is 为期？ Could it ever be used in a regular conversation?

Answer (score 3):

**Could I say something in the past tense that wasn't expected like "战争为期十年“?**

Yes you can.

`为期` is originally a V-O phrase, literally,

- 为: as, being
- 期: period, deadline

Putting them together, `为期` means `(to be done) by/within (a certain period)`, which implies the limit is intentionally set. E.g.

> 我等你，三年为期。 I'll wait for you for 3 years.

However, the phrase 为期 as a whole can also be used as a verb, and with that usage the sense of 'intentionally set time limit' is dimmed. It merely means `to last`. E.g.

> 为期三年的等待。A waiting that lasted for 3 years.

`战争为期十年` is another example for this usage.

---

**How formal is 为期？ Could it ever be used in a regular conversation?**

It sounds formal, but it could be used in regular conversation.

In spoken language, the shorter the sentence is, the more people tend to avoid using formal words. So if `战争为期十年` is the whole sentence, it sounds more casual to say `战争持续了十年` or even more colloquially `战争打了十年`.

In a long sentence though, it is okay to use formal words if they can shorten the sentence or simplify sentence structure. Because `为期` is shorter than `持续了`, `在一场为期十年的战争里，...` doesn't sound too much more serious than `在一场持续了十年的战争里, ...`. This rule applies to other formal/informal phrases too.